# Scrum in traditional management structure

Tags: scrum

We are acting Scrum in our department now. But the up level management structure is traditional, such as Project Manager(PM), Development Manager(DM), Team Leader(TL) and Test team leader(TTL).

Team Leader act as a Scrum master, he controls all the things in our team: communicated with PM/DM/TTL, development management... Our PO's responsibility is just maintaining PBL.

Our managers and team member are accustomed to the traditional management type, they do not care Scrum, and they said some Scrum rules are hidebound.
I act as another SM, I want to change the current status.

But I haven't any headship, just is an ordinary developer in our department. Does anyone has this kind of bother too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are plenty of Scrum-related questions in SO.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5):

I heard a lovely saying once and can't remember who said it. "They want Agile but they don't know what it is - so we give them Agile but we don't know what they want."

It sounds as if this is happening in your company. Someone, somewhere wants the team to use Scrum, but it's not the team.

That must be a difficult job for an SM, especially if you're doing it unofficially! There are some things I can suggest for you. First, learn some basic coaching techniques: positive language, [GROW framework](http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newLDR_89.htm) and [giving and receiving feedback](http://andypalmer.com/2009/05/making-feedback-more-effective/). This will give you some additional tools which are outside of Scrum and support someone in a leadership rather than a management position (even an unofficial SM can become a leader).

Then, don't worry about the actual practices. If someone has mandated Scrum then the team will be forced to do this anyway. Instead, concentrate on the values and principles of Scrum - particularly collaboration, communication and transparency. Help the team to work with each other instead of being silo'd away. You will have to be an example for them. Don't mandate pair programming, but do go over and pair. Don't mandate stand-ups, but do have conversations first thing in the morning and draw in as many people on the team as you can. Look at the principle of "Continuous Improvement". Learn how to do [root cause analysis and the 5 Why's](http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newTMC_5W.htm) so that the team can understand better why things are hard and take action themselves.

I also recommend [Mary Lynn Manns and Linda Rising "Fearless Change"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201741571). This will help you to work out who else could help you.

Finally, I will echo @sjt. Don't commit Scrum suicide. However, if it's something you really want and your company aren't doing it in the right way, don't be afraid to look elsewhere. Learn some of the fundamentals, practice TDD on your own and find a new job.

Whatever you do, good luck! The first step to change is desire.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have buy in from your other developers its not going to work. Period.

Scrum requires a heap of discipline, especially during the early adoption phase.

I wouldn't be bothered that management don't care for it.  If you're free to do the work of developing the software, and all they care about is results, then it shouldn't matter if you happen to have a 10 minute stand up each morning, and plan small chunks of the work into manageable bits, as long as you're hitting the targets they want you to hit.

If you're team isn't on board though, you're going to have a **really** hard time getting it working, and it will probably fail and cause more impact that not having tried at all.

If you can try to start it in a small project, with a few developers who are on board with the idea, then you can report back to the rest of your development team on how you found it works, what were the benefits and what were the negatives (reflecting is after all an important part of Scrum).

If you want to get your management on board, you might find that after doing a few projects this way you're much better at estimating the time it will take to develop the requirements you've been given by the PMs, hopefully being able to hit deadlines with more accuracy.

Remember, the PMs and BAs can still work in their normal way, once they've handed requirements to you, you're able to build them using Scrum.  Its not ideal, but short of having the buy in of everyone, and the ability to speak directly to users and get them to help write user stories, it will be the best you've got.

When asked to estimate the time it will take to complete the project you can apply Scrum techniques.  You can break the specifications down into smaller chunks, group them into sprints and develop them accordingly, hopefully yielding better results.

Answer (score 2):

> "I act as another SM, I want to change the current status"

Well, that's a good start right there, wanting to change the situation. Although I must say that without the management buy in, it will be tough. Try and arrange an experienced Scrum Speaker or Agile Coach come and do a presentation or workshop at your company which involves all the upper management. Once you have the management believing in Scrum, it will be all downhill from there.

> "Team Leader act as a Scrum master, he controls all the things is our team"

This goes against the Self Organized and Self empowering Teams principle in Scrum. A good Scrum Master would empower the Team in a disciplined fashion within the Scrum Rules, to that appropriate level that, the Team should be able to run on it's own. One suggestion is that the Team Leads need to have a different mindset when working as a SM and different one while working as a Senior Developer, there are no Team Leads in a Scrum Team, only Scrum Team members. You cannot assign true leadership, that is a mutual role which can be earned by creating a reputation of helping others and mentoring others. Have them spit time between SM and development duties 30%, 70% or 50-50 or whatever you find appropriate. Command and control could be counter productive for the Team.

> Our managers and team member are accustomed to the traditional management type, they do not care Scrum

A Scrum Trainer had told once told me, "Do not commit Scrum Suicide". If your managers do not care about Scrum, don't get fired trying to convince them. Whatever methodology you guys might follow or "not" follow, you have to realise that all this is a business. Your pay check is dependent on your boss's approval, if your boss or manager does not care about Scrum, then don;t do it. If they care about waterfall, Switch to it, do it like you care, but don't do Scrum halfway and call it scrum.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in the past is to identify and communicate pain-points. Certainly, you should never do something because Kent Beck told you to, especially something that will just get you fired. However, some smart people worked at figuring out a set of practices which is cohesive, and divergence from these practices almost always leads to pain points.

As just one example: if you do Scrum where you have a requirements iteration, a design iteration, an implementation iteration, and a testing iteration, this in theory could work but in practice never does. (When it does, it ends up being Waterfall, and the "iteration" notion becomes meaningless.) Pointing out to your boss that you learned something about the requirements while QA was testing might help him realize there's value in getting QA involved in requirements. Or finding risks in the software design by doing a small prototype may help to show why it might help to collapse the design iteration.